# Fetching only first 100 rows of image from mediastore

Tags: android, limit, android-sdcard

Is there a way to limit the result retrieved from mediastore using managedQuery function on Android. Since I currently have a grid that displaying all photos found on the sd card but it is too intensive of fetching it so I decide to limit the result retrieved from the media store but could not find a limit function that can reduce the resulting set of data.

Please help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use order in contentresolver's query method to implement your function,
such as 'columnname asc limit number'

in my case:

```
cursor = resolver.query(STORAGE_URI, projection,
                        Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + "=?",
                        new String[] { folderName },
                        " _id asc limit " + num);
```

Comment: and you need the "<column name> asc" part, you can't just put "limit N".

Comment: Make sure not to use string formatting to create the parameter as it performs localization by default, i.e. the following statement will cause SQL exception on arabic phones: `String sortOrder = String.format(" _id asc limit (%d)", num);`

Comment: @TomSusel Rather do not rely on the default locale :)

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the result using the sortOrder parameter in [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) method. Something like this

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor androidCursor = null;
String sortOrder = String.format("%s limit 100",BaseColumns._ID);
androidCursor = contentResolver.query(IMAGE_URI,PROJECTION, null, null, sortOrder);
```

This will order the result set by id and limit the result.

Answer (score 2):

When targeting Android 11 the suggested answer will cause an exception, with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token LIMIT`

Instead you should provide a "limit" query parameter on the URI that the MediaProvider will read.

```
val queryUri = IMAGE_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limit", limit.toString()).build()
```

I haven't found documentation for this, but it's present in the [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java)

Comment: This didn't work for me, this query param was ignored.